# Efficient Method to Compute Geometric Series of a Matrix

Tags: matrices

I have a problem. please help me to solve it. 
As we know, the geometric series of a matrix $A_{n\times n} $ is defined as 
$\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} A^l$. This series converges to $(1-A)^{-1}$  if and only if $\rho(A) <1$, where $\rho(A)$  is the eigenvalue with maximum magnitude. For every matrix $A$, we can generate a regularized matrix $rA$ where $0 < r < \frac {1}{\rho(A)}$. Know it can be proved that $\rho(rA)<1$ and hence 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(rA)^l =\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}r^lA^l = (I-rA)^{-1}
\end{equation*}
Calculating such an inverse is of order $O(n^{2.37})$.

Now suppose that a new matrix $B_{(n+1)\times (n+1)}$ is given such that:

1) $B_{1:n,1:n} = A$, that is $B$ is generated by adding a row and a column to A's ends.

2) $B_{n+1,:} = B_{:,n+1}^T$

The following matrices are examples of $A$ and $B$:

\begin{bmatrix}
    1.1 & 2.3 \\
    3.4 & 4.5
  \end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
    1.1 & 2.3 & 4.2 \\
    3.4 & 4.5 & 5.2 \\
    4.2 & 5.2 & 4.7
  \end{bmatrix}

Considering that $(I-rA)^{-1}$ (geometric series of regularized $A$) is given, is there any way to compute geometric series of regularized $B$ with any way faster than $O(n+1)^{2.73}$???

Comment: With what value do you regularize $B$ ? and do you have $(I-rA)^{-1}$ for all $r$ ?

Comment: $B$ is regularized by $0<r'<\frac{1}{\rho(B)}$. No, I'm using $r=\frac{0.9}{\rho(A)}$.